# Финки в значении спортивные штаны

Tags: лексика, стилистика

В Армении как коренные армяне, так и бакинские армяне (последние — русскоязычные),  в обиходе про спортивные штаны говорят: финки. Распространено это слово и в Азербайджане. Это бакинский сленг.

А вам, русским, это слово в этом значении известно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, в данном значении "финки" - это *региональный* разговорный элемент: он встречается в форумах, связанных с Баку; в одной из книг автор пишет, что кроме как в Баку, нигде не слышал этого слова в значении спортивных брюк. Словари фиксируют "финки" в значении финских саней (их выдают напрокат зимой в некоторых парках крупных городов), но и в этом значении слово не везде употребляется (в Петербурге ни разу не слышал). Вот "финка" широко употреблялось в значении "финский нож" (холодное оружие); сейчас иногда этим словом неформально упоминают Финляндию (съездить в "финку").

Происхождение "финок" как штанов неясно. Слово созвучно с "трениками", но возникло оно явно раньше, поэтому вряд ли есть связь между этими словами. Возможно, это название смутно указывало на "северную страну", из которой когда-то пришла мода. Например, "финкой" (согласно словарям) называют и лошадь одной из *северных* пород. А возможно, в советские времена попавшая в Баку партия импорта из Финляндии дала неформальное название ставшему там популярным виду спортивной одежды.

Comment: @Alex_andr,  а лично вам известно это значение у данного слова?

Comment: Нет, для меня это новое значение.

Comment: @Alex_andr, а вы как называете их - треники?

Comment: Нет, просто "спортивными" штанами. "Тренировочными" раньше называли конкретный фасон (синие, обтягивающие, с рельефными стрелками спереди), от этого слова позже пошёл жаргон "треники".